# How to pass data from one html page to other html using jquery in phonegap ios

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

I am working on Phonegap ios. I want to know how to pass data from one html page to other using jquery.

In the first html page (Home.html), I have a Textfield to enter user name. In this there is **Next** button. When I click next button I have to move the data that I entered for T.F. to other html page and display it as label.

As I am a newbie to the phonegap ios, Plz help me in this.

Comment: Assuming that you have all your pages in a single HTML page with data roles defined as "page". Make a data/model object and update the objects member. example : your  object is "User", in a global scope, var User = {}; User.name = "username"; //assign here, and call your object in usual way, User.name will give you the name stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to post data that you want next page.

Answer (score 0):

just as you do for developing normal web pages.Submit the form to other page and on the other page get the data from query string